# Is there a way to choose an item in autocomplete with the space key?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I'm typing and I get autocomplete appear eg/if I type `ret` I get a list of values to choose from:

[image: auto complete]

Is there a way I can get Sublime to choose one of the items by pressing the spacebar rather than having to type tab?

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea isn't it?

Imagine you want to write somthing like `ret abc` for example. This wouldn't be possible because at the moment you press the spacebar it would select the first item from the auto complete list, in this case `returns`.

This would make it really cumbersome to write code, so this is not possible.

But it is possible to assign another shortcut to choose an item.

#### Example for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

insert into user keybinding.

```
{ "keys": ["alt+space"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

#### //Edit:

For *space ONLY* the `keys` argument is NOT `space` but a literally space `" "`. Don't know if this is a feature or a bug but this is the solution to the original question.

```
{ "keys": [" "], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I was trying to imitate Visual Studio but you're right in that when you type space it does select first item in the list but I'm not sure in reality its an issue

Comment: I remember that some time ago it was an issue for me where exactly this behavior really sucked. The behavior in Visual Studio is a little more sophisticated I think. They may have a good algorithm to avoid these problems as I never came across them in VS. Non the less the hack I suggested doesn't work for space only.

Comment: Just remembered how I had activated this option some time ago. See my edited answer. Just an opinion, but I still think it's no good idea having space as auto complete trigger. Anyway this answer should do the trick now.